# DataTable.LoadDataRow not loading data into DataTable in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Below is the code i have used to load data into `MismatchedData`  `DataTable`:

```
ReportData_Batch = reptDataAccess.GetFromBatch(numberOfDays, carriersstr);
ReportData_Tran = reptDataAccess.GetFromTran();

DataTable MismatchedData = CreateDataTable();

IEnumerable<DataRow> TotalMisMatchedRecords = from Batchdata in ReportData_Batch.AsEnumerable()
                                              join Trancm in ReportData_Transcom.AsEnumerable()
                                              on Batchdata["LoadID"].ToString()
                                              equals Trancm["lean_load_id"].ToString() into loads
                                              from nullvalue in loads.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                              where nullvalue==null
                                              select MismatchedData.LoadDataRow(
                                              new object[] { Batchdata["LoadID"].ToString(),
                                              Batchdata["AltCarrierDesignation"].ToString(),
                                              Batchdata["Carrier"].ToString(),
                                              Batchdata["createDate"].ToString(),
                                              Batchdata["vendorcode"].ToString()    
                                              }, true);

int  TotalCount= TotalMisMatchedRecords.Count();
```

The problem here it is not loading any data into MismatchedData datatable but i can see data in `IEnumerable<DataRow> TotalMisMatchedRecords`. One surprise thing is if I use any statement like `TotalMisMatchedRecords.Count()` after LINQ query i can see data in `MismatchedData` .if i remove that `TotalCount`  Statement, there is no data in `MismatchedData` .

Comment: Linq IEnumerable<t> queries are not executed immediately and are deferred until called, use ToList() etc to execute the query immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use LINQ-**Queries** to load or modify something. Instead you could use `CopyToDataTable` or a `foreach`-loop:

```
MismatchedData = TotalMisMatchedRecords.CopyToDataTable();
```

**Update**

> I am loading all data using MismatchedData.LoadDataRow() into
>   MismatchedData DataTable .why do i need to use CopyToDataTable()
>   again?

That's a good question and actually you're right. Note that your LINQ query is deferred executed which means that it's currently just the definition of the query not the result. If you would *execute* the query your table would be filled with the rows.

So even this strange loop which seemingly does nothing will fill the table because it executes the query:

```
foreach (var row in TotalMisMatchedRecords) ;
```

That's also the reason why you only see the result after you use a method like `TotalMisMatchedRecords.Count()`. It executes the ([deferred executed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)) query.

That's why i've mentioned in the first sentence that i would **avoid side-effects in a LINQ query** like modification of an existing table or collection. It's just confusing and can cause nasty errors.

That's why i  prefer code like this:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> TotalMisMatchedRecords = from Batchdata in ReportData_Batch.AsEnumerable()
                                              join Trancm in ReportData_Transcom.AsEnumerable()
                                              on Batchdata["LoadID"].ToString()
                                              equals Trancm["lean_load_id"].ToString() into loads
                                              from nullvalue in loads.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                              where nullvalue == null
                                              select Batchdata;

foreach (DataRow batchRow in TotalMisMatchedRecords)
    MismatchedData.Rows.Add(
        batchRow["LoadID"].ToString(),
        batchRow["AltCarrierDesignation"].ToString(),
        batchRow["Carrier"].ToString(),
        batchRow["createDate"].ToString(),
        batchRow["vendorcode"].ToString()
        );
```

Comment: Then How should be my select statement in LINQ?

Comment: I am asking about LINQ query,not about CopyToDataTable() method

Comment: @user3243251: but your LINQ query seems to be  fine. I have tested it. So the only what i'm missing is that you execute the query somehow. Since you want a new DataTable you can use `CopyToDataTable`.

Comment: I am loading all data using MismatchedData.LoadDataRow() into MismatchedData DataTable .why do i need to use CopyToDataTable() again?

Comment: @user3243251: i have edited my answer to explain it and to provide an alternative.